# How to execute .sql files present on windows machine on a remotely connected mysql server?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I have a .sql file on windows that I want to run on mysql server that is present on centOS. I am using the following command to connect and execute the .sql file-

> mysql -u user_name -ppassw0rd -h [ip address of centOS] -P [port used
>   by mysql server] --verbose < file path on windows.

But on executing this command i am getting an error as :

> ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 3: Lost connection to MySQL server during
>   query

### Also is there any way to see the errors that occur when query is executed.

Note - I am using mysql command line tool on windows to run the above command.

Comment: i have tried setting --wait_timeout but it doesn't help.

Comment: do you have any firewall rules on the mysql machine preventing you access from localhost?

Comment: i can access my mysql machine

Comment: i have checked that already....

Comment: http://jerrywalsh.org/2009/solving-mysql-error-2013-hy000-0130.html